# Get largest Group of anagrams in an array

Tags: java, arrays, anagram

For an assignment I have been asked to find the largest group of anagrams in a list.  I believe I would have to have an accumulation loop inside of another loop that keeps track of the largest number of items. The problem is that I don't know how to count how many of each anagram I have.  I have been able to sort the array into groups based on their anagrams. So from the index 1-3 is one anagram, 4-10 is another, etc. How do I search through and count how many of each anagram I have? Then compare each one to the previous count.

Sample of the code:

```
public static String[] getLargestAnagramGroup(String[] inputArray) {

    ArrayList<String> largestGroupArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (inputArray.length == 0 || inputArray == null) {
        return new String[0];
    }

    insertionSort(inputArray, new AnagramComparator());

    String[] largestGroupArray = new String[largestGroupArrayList.size()];
    largestGroupArrayList.toArray(inputArray);
    System.out.println(largestGroupArray);
    return largestGroupArray;
}
```

**UPDATE:** This is how we solved it. Is there a more efficient way?

```
public static String[] getLargestAnagramGroup(String[] inputArray) {

    int numberOfAnagrams = 0;
    int temporary = 1;
    int position = -1;
    int index = 0;

    if (inputArray == null) {
        return new String[0];
    }
    insertionSort(inputArray, new AnagramComparator());
    for (index = 0; index < inputArray.length - 1; index++) {
        if (areAnagrams(inputArray[index], inputArray[index + 1])) {
            temporary++;
        } else {
            if (temporary > numberOfAnagrams) {
                numberOfAnagrams = temporary;
                position = index;
                temporary = 1;
            } else if (temporary < numberOfAnagrams) {
                temporary = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (temporary > numberOfAnagrams) {
        position = index;
        numberOfAnagrams = temporary;
    }
    String[] largestArray = new String[numberOfAnagrams];
    for (int startIndex = position - numberOfAnagrams + 1, i = 0; startIndex <= position; startIndex++, i++) {
        largestArray[i] = inputArray[startIndex];
    }

    return largestArray;
}
```

Comment: What does AnagramComparator do?

Comment: @NewUser AnagramComparator compares 2 indexes and tells me if they're anagrams or not. It is used in the InsertionSort method to sort the list with all the anagram groups next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code to help you out.

```
public class AnagramTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = {"test", "ttes", "abcd", "dcba", "dbac"};

    for (String string : getLargestAnagramGroup(input)) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

/**
 * Gives an array of Strings which are anagrams and has the highest occurrence. 
 * 
 * @param inputArray
 * @return
 */
public static String[] getLargestAnagramGroup(String[] inputArray) {
    // Creating a linked hash map to maintain the order
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

    for (String string : inputArray) {
        char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(charArray);
        String sortedStr = new String(charArray);
        List<String> anagrams = map.get(sortedStr);
        if (anagrams == null) {
            anagrams = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        anagrams.add(string);

        map.put(sortedStr, anagrams);
    }

    Set<Entry<String, List<String>>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    int highestAnagrams = -1;
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : entrySet) {
        List<String> value = entry.getValue();
        if (value.size() > highestAnagrams) {
            highestAnagrams = value.size();
            l = value;
        }
    }

    return l.toArray(new String[l.size()]);
}
}
```

The idea is to first find the anangrams. I am doing that using a sorting the string's character array and using the `LinkedhashMap`.

Then I am storing the original string in the list which can be used to print or reuse as a result.

You have to keep counting the number of times the an anagram occurs and that value can be used solve your problem

Comment: I'm already able to find if they are anagrams of each other. The problem was just finding out how to count them. The end goal was to return an array with the largest group.

Comment: @ZacharyKing : The `String[]` which is returned, has the highest number of anagrams. Hence, the size of the array should be your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in C#.

```
public static string[] LargestAnagramsSet(string[] words)
{
    var maxSize = 0;
    var maxKey = string.Empty;

    Dictionary<string, List<string>> set = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        char[] temp = words[i].ToCharArray();
        Array.Sort(temp);

        var key = new string(temp);

        if (set.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            set[key].Add(words[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            var anagrams = new List<string>
            {
                words[i]
            };
            set.Add(key, anagrams);
        }
        if (set[key].Count() > maxSize)
        {
            maxSize = set[key].Count();
            maxKey = key;
        }
    }
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(maxKey) ? words : set[maxKey].ToArray();
}
```